# Problemas al mostrar datos en una plantilla blade

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

Recientemente estoy viendo base de datos en laravel y vistas en blade pero al momento de mostrar la informacion de una tabla en un una extension de la plantilla base de blade se me desordena o no me muestra.

Esta es la plantilla base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practica DBt</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1, h2, h3{
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        h3{
            color: red;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>UNIVERSIDAD TECNICA DEL NORTE</h1>
        <h2>FACULTAD DE INGENERIAS</h2>
        <h3>EJERCICIOS DE BASE DE DATOS</h3>
        @yield("parte1")
    </div>
    <div>
        yield("parte2")
    </div>
    <div>
        yield("parte3")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la extension:

```
@extends("base")
@section("parte1")
<h2>DATOS DE FACULTAD</h2>
@endsection

@section("parte2")
    @if(count($resultados))
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
              <td>ID</td><td>NOMBRE</td><td>DECANO</td><td>SECRETARIA</td><td>UBICACION</td><td>TELEFONO</td><td>TELEFONO</td><td>CREACION</td><td>ACTUALIZACION</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach($resultados as $fila)
                <tr>
                   @foreach($fila as $dato)
                      <td>{{$dato}}</td>
                   @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
   @endif
@endsection
```

Al momento de correr en el navegador se me muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le quito el @endsection final se muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que quiero que la tabla se coloque abajo del titulo, miro y miro y no encuentro el error. Necesito ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Nota: Los datos de la tabla son ficticios no se preocupen.

Comment: ¿No te falta el @ en el `yield("parte2")` y `yield("parte3")`?

Comment: Además, no hace falta que utilices un `@if` para pintar la tabla. Te recomiendo que **siempre** pintes la tabla y las celdas de cabecera. Así te aseguras de mostrar algo, en lugar de no mostrar nada.
Ya si quieres validar que te pinte los renglones solo si existen, puedes utilizar un `@forelse`.

Comment: Lo primero, gracias, nunca me di cuenta, xd, lo segundo lo pondre en practica a ver si me sale.